# vb.net SQL update query cannot completed

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

i am trying to execute this update query in a vb.net application:

```
SQL = "UPDATE billing_calldata SET status = 'c', customer = '" & customer_sequence & "', description = '" & description & "', customer_cost = '" & customer_cost & "', customer_ac = '" & customer_ac & "', customer_sc = '" & customer_sc & "', reseller_cost = '" & reseller_cost & "', reseller_ac = '" & reseller_ac & "', reseller_sc = '" & reseller_sc & "' WHERE sequence = '" & sequence & "';"
```

but its taking ages and not even completing.

on the `ExecuteNonQuery()` its saying:

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

what could be causing it to not complete?

i have copied the query (with the correct values) and tried to run directly on the server which takes about 49 secs (but it actually completes)

i have added an index on my `sequence` column in the table

Comment: Do you know that creating SQL that way will crash if the customer is say, `Ziggy's Hardware`? And that it forces those cost items to string?  Use SQL Parameters

Comment: what do you have against newlines?

Comment: @Plutonix the customer column is only ever an integer so will never have any `'`

Comment: Ok and the `'" & customer_sequence & "'` will convert the integer to string.  Always use SQL Parameters

Answer (score 3):

You could try to set the CommandTimeout to an higher value. The default is 30 seconds for Sql Server, I have no reference for MySql but it could be equal. So, if your command executed on the server takes 49 seconds, then a Timeout of 30 seconds from your code it is surely a showstopper.

```
 command.CommandTimeout = 60
```

However let me warn you about a bigger problem in you query. This query could be easily hacked with an Sql Injection scheme. It is better that you search as soon as possible for Parameterized queries and change you coding habits.

**EDIT** The Timeout for a MySqlCommand is 30 seconds as for Sql Server.
[Found a reference here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-mysqlcommand.html)

Comment: If you look at `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionTimeout` when using it, the default is 15

Comment: Ack!  Sorry, I got confused.

Comment: i understand about the Sql Injection issues but this application is only ever used by me and its how it was written a while ago so its okay. i just want to know why the query is taking so long to run even directly on the SQL server (without using vb.net) - it seems like a fairly simple query to me?

Comment: I disagree, it is just not a matter of Sql Injection, but also a parsing problem. If your fields are not a of string type the db engine needs to convert each value to the appropriate type (number, dates, decimals) and index lookup could be discarded cause these conversions. Not to mention the single quote problems. For example what if 'description' value contains a single quote? To avoid a syntax error you are forced to execute a Replace to double the single quote. At the end your string sql becomes a maintenance and understandabilty nightmare. Trust me, parameters makes your life easier.

Comment: but even running the query directly in phpmyadmin takes a long time - its not just vb.net

Comment: How many rows are present in your table? Do you have an index on the column Sequence?

Comment: Just over 1m rows. Yeah index is on sequence column, it's also primary

Comment: the query that is being run is `UPDATE billing_calldata SET 
status = 'c', 
customer = 470, 
description = 'Mobile', 
customer_cost = 0.006175, 
customer_ac = 0, 
customer_sc = 0, 
reseller_cost = 0, 
reseller_ac = 0, 
reseller_sc = 0 
WHERE sequence = 10348384;"` - i tried clearing the table so the `sequence` column is starting at 1 and the update query works fine