# vb.net SQL query will not run - timing out

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to run this query in vb.net but every time it's timing out because it's taking over 49 seconds.

```
Dim customer_sequence As Integer = 0
Dim description As String = ""
Dim customer_cost As Double = 0
Dim customer_connection As Double = 0
Dim customer_ac As Double = 0
Dim customer_sc As Double = 0
Dim reseller_cost As Double = 0
Dim reseller_connection As Double = 0
Dim reseller_ac As Double = 0
Dim reseller_sc As Double = 0

SQL = "UPDATE billing_calldata SET " _
                        & "status = 'c', " _
                        & "customer = " & customer_sequence & ", " _
                        & "description = '" & description & "', " _
                        & "customer_cost = " & customer_cost & ", " _
                        & "customer_ac = " & customer_ac & ", " _
                        & "customer_sc = " & customer_sc & ", " _
                        & "reseller_cost = " & reseller_cost & ", " _
                        & "reseller_ac = " & reseller_ac & ", " _
                        & "reseller_sc = " & reseller_sc & " " _
                        & "WHERE sequence = " & sequence & ";"
```

The output of the query is:

```
UPDATE billing_calldata SET 
status = 'c', 
customer = 470, 
description = 'Mobile', 
customer_cost = 0.006175, 
customer_ac = 0, 
customer_sc = 0, 
reseller_cost = 0, 
reseller_ac = 0, 
reseller_sc = 0 
WHERE sequence = 10348384;"
```

All other queries in my app are working fine and fast but it's just this one that takes ages.

Comment: Pretty much a [duplicate/repost](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37262159/1070452)

Comment: This is a SQL question until you provide your code where you execute the query.

Comment: sorry, that wasnt suppose to be there. it was in the actual code

Comment: `WHERE sequence = 10348384;"` Why the end semicolon? what for?

Comment: It's just what I put at the end of my queries by default - it's a terminator to say it's the end of the query. For example if I am running 2 queries in one statement you would separate them with a ;

Comment: It's completely useless. And you should not concatenate commands and/or queries.

Comment: Ok I've removed it and still the same issue. I also cleared my table and tried with fresh data and it works fine so it looks like it's the 'sequence' being such a large number. How can I fix that?

Comment: You are using an **integer**, and the value you are showing is in range. But in your database you are possibly using a too narrow data type .

Comment: my database looks like this - http://postimg.org/image/berij6avf/

Comment: You need to use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.  Hmm, sequence is a BigInt?  How many records are in this table?  Does your table have indexes?  You have `customer = 470` and yet, customer is a `varchar(10)`.  How long does it take if you try to just `SELECT * FROM billing_calldata WHERE sequence  = 10348384`?  Your *_cost sound like accounting fields — you have them as floats.  Those should be decimal or money type fields.

Comment: currently the number of rows is 10400230 but its growing and adds a few thousand every day. customer is always a number, should that be another type? and yep the *_cost fields are all monetry values but i thought float was correct. the main thing at the moment is the sequence column that is causing an issue on update

Comment: If you execute the same query in SSMS, does it goes faster or does it takes "age" ?

Comment: I'm not sure, What is SSMS?

Comment: For the initiated, it stands for Sql Server Management Studio. 
Do you have it somewhere ? It should be installed on your SQL server but if not, you can download it and use it to connect to SQL server. It is basically the "visual studio" for SQL developpers.

Comment: The database is MySQL. I tried running the query in phpmyadmin and it's still very slow

Comment: Oh, you didn't mentionned that in your original message. I thought it was MSSQL. Hmmm... I'm not as familiar with Mysql. My answer is not what you seek then. The fact that it is very slow in php admin might indicate that the query is just slow since you have a lot of rows.

Comment: Ah sorry! :) hmm it's a weird one. Not seen anything like it before - insert is okay, it's just update that's taking a long time

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the same issue when executing query in SSMS ?
If so,

I had an issue, at the enterprise I work for, where some queries were excessively slow using ADO (through our App.) when compared to doing the exact same query in SSMS.

In our case, setting ARITHABORT to ON when initializing ADO connection solved our issue.

```
SET ARITHABORT ON
```

You only need to do it once per connection so you could use a method such as
the one below to open your connection and set the option first.

```
Public Shared Sub OpenAndSetArithAbort(MyConnection As SqlConnection)
Using _Command As SqlCommand = MyConnection.CreateCommand()
    _Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    _Command.CommandText = "SET ARITHABORT ON;"

    MyConnection.Open()

    _Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

End Sub

Here is the reason (see at the end for reference).

Your application connects with ARITHABORT OFF, but when you run the query in SSMS, ARITHABORT is ON and thus you will not reuse the cache entry that the application uses, but SQL Server will compile the procedure anew, sniffing your current parameter values, and you may get a different plan than from the application. So there you have a likely answer to the initial question of this article. There are a few more possibilities that we will look into in the next chapter, but the by far most common reason for slow in the application, fast in SSMS in SQL 2005 and later is parameter sniffing and the different defaults for ARITHABORT.

Reference: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: im using MySQL but the same issue is happening on phpmyadmin

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not well used to MySQL. 
Maybe it's a MYSQL server performance issue due to your table being very large. Take a look at this
http://www.tocker.ca/2013/10/24/improving-the-performance-of-large-tables-in-mysql.html

Answer (score 1):

After reading some of the other comments posted, have you looked into the last time your table was analyzed?

```
EXPLAIN Update billing SET col1, col2,.... where sequence = 12345;
```

Refer to this to help you understand the output.  Verify if you're actuallying using the index in that query.
[https://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/][1]

For tables that are highly transactional, it's good to keep the analyze up to date.  Basically, if it's not analyzed, the database can have problems deciding whether or not to use an index to fetch a tuple and possibly fall back to a full-table scan (which in this case it sounds like what is happening....).

Once you have an up-to-date analyze, the MySql optimizer will know the best way to access the records you've requested.

Insert works fine because there's no full scan is needed... just pop in row assuming you don't violate a key or constraint of some kind.

Update needs to navigate to where that records resides to update the relevant fields... and if doing full table scans this will severely degrade performance, especially in larger tables.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to add an index on the `billing_calldata` table to the `sequence` column in order to improve performance.

Depending on your db platform, it will look similar to below. (This is a SQL Server example):

```
CREATE INDEX i_billing_calldata_sequence ON billing_calldata (sequence);
```

Comment: Any ideas on this?

Comment: There are over 1m rows

Comment: any thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Run an explain plan on your update query.  Yes you might see the index exists... but are you actually using it?  Explain will tell you that.  If you're not, analyze your table and run it again and see what happens.